# is there any encryption algorithm that don't increase the output size?

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption

assume i have this text: `my message will be encrypt`
i need an algorithm to encrypt it with my key like `mykey`
but don't increase output size greater than input size! i.e my message is 26 character length and encrypted output size be lower or equal.

Language: PHP or anything else ...

I used this blowfish encryption but output is larger than input and `gzcompress` didn't help:

```
function encrypt_blowfish($pure_string,$key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, hash('sha256', $key, TRUE), utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $encrypted_string = bin2hex($encrypted_string);

    return $encrypted_string;
}

function decrypt_blowfish($encrypted_string,$key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $encrypted_string = hex2bin($encrypted_string);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, hash('sha256', $key, TRUE), $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $decrypted_string = trim($decrypted_string);

    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Comment: why -1? is there problem?

Comment: Did you try anything? People here do not like questions if you tried nothing.

Comment: so any of the compression algorithms, zip\rar etc

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography And answer is yes. There are algorithms that would encode one message to the same size message.

Comment: compression algorithm did not did not help!

Comment: how long is the string ?

Comment: @Dagon You mean *how long is a piece a string* - See, even I/they don't know. ;-)

Comment: @Dagon: string length is variable but my be 10-50 characters.

Comment: due to overhead, nothing is going to make 10-50 characters encrypted securely smaller; depending on your level of security needs your own substitution cypher would be trivial to implement.

Comment: overhead? you mean there is no encryption method that hasn't overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream ciphers (e.g. RC4) or block ciphers (e.g. AES) in streaming mode such as CTR will do that. They work by producing a pseudo-random stream of bytes which is the XORed with the plaintext to get the ciphertext. Depending on your use case there is either no overhead with RC4 or only little overhead with AES due to the IV.

AES in CTR mode is considered secure whereas RC4 has some problems.

Example of RC4 with an 2048-bit key (max):

```
$cipher = "arcfour";
$k = mcrypt_create_iv(256); // random
$data = "some string";
$mode = "stream";

echo "data size: " . strlen($data) . "\n"; // 11

echo "key size: ".mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher, $mode)."\n";
echo "iv size: ".mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, $mode)."\n";

$c = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $k, $data , $mode, "");
echo "ciphertext size: " . strlen($c) . "\n"; // 11
```

This is an example of AES-CTR with an 256-bit key (max):

```
$cipher = "rijndael-128";
$k = mcrypt_create_iv(32); // random
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16); // random
$data = "some string";
$mode = "ctr";

echo "key size: ".mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher, $mode)."\n";
echo "iv size: ".mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, $mode)."\n";

$c = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $k, $data , $mode, $iv);
echo "ciphertext size: " . strlen($c) . "\n"; // 11
```

Note that the IV must be present for AES and it must be the same size as the block. It must be random, but not necessarily secret.

Answer (score 0):

In general though, you would go through two steps - compress then encrypt or encrypt then compress. Some methods combine both, such as encrypted zip files.

However, compression won't provide benefit if your messages are short enough.

There are some encryption methods (such as the trivial ROT13) that produce output the same length as the input, though I'm not aware of a standard implementation of a secure encryption algorithm that shows those characteristics.

Comment: yes i know. but in short messages compression don't work. some of algorithms aren't so secure.

Comment: You never encrypt then compress -- any real encryption method won't produce a compressible output.